# c# substring indexof

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

i have a string which looks like this -
`"FirstName||Sam LastName||Jones Address||123 Main ST ..."` (100 more different values)

I want to find only Sam and Jones from the entire string.

so string `firstname = originalstring.substring` ... etc.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

ADDITION -
I think i forgot to mention couple of things.

```
FirstName||Sam\r\n MiddleName||\r\n LastName||Jones\r\n ....
```

So now if i count the number of characters that wont help me, cause could need more items other than just *firstname* and *lastname*.

Comment: I'm not clear on how the original string is formatted. It appears there is one item of data per line on your string, is this correct? Does each string have multiple person records, or is there only one person record in each string?

Comment: When I took a peek behind your editing, it appeared that you have multiple lines. But the formatting that StackOverflow is applying to your question (actually that HTML is applying to your question) is smashing those down onto one line. Thus my confusion.

Comment: I hope my explanation has cleared out your question Charlie. And to everyone here, a big thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Is there only one person in the entire string, and you need the first and last name?  Or are there multiple people in the string, and you need to find more than one last name and first name?

Answer (score 8):

Use **Regular expressions**:

```
string myString = "FirstName||Sam LastName||Jones Address||123 Main ST...";
string pattern = @"FirstName\|\|(\w+) LastName\|\|(\w+) ";
Match m = Regex.Match(myString, pattern);
string firstName = m.Groups[1].Value
string lastName = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

## See its Demo [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/lrgFV8vLee).

Comment: I like how no-one else suggested regex's :) +1 for that.

Answer (score 5):

I think this might work better than the .Split approach.  If you had || between 'Sam' and 'LastName' then you'd certainly want to .Split.  As it is, this might be better.

```
    string inStr = "FirstName||Sam LastName||Jones Address||123 Main ST ";
    int fStart = inStr.IndexOf("FirstName") + "FirstName".Length + "||".Length;
    int fEnd = inStr.IndexOf(" LastName");

    string FirstName = inStr.Substring(fStart, fEnd - fStart);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split the string twice once on " " and then again on || to get the values of first and last name

```
string [] ary = s.Split(" ");
string [] key;
string firstname;
string lastname;
foreach (string val in ary ) {
    key = val.Split("||");
    if ( key[0] == "FirstName") {
         firstname = key[1];
}
if ( key[0] == "LastName") {
   lastname = key[1];
}
}
```

Comment: Works until you get a name containing a space.

Comment: Splitting on ' ' won't work even in the example - check the street name (if those are required anyway)

Comment: splitting on ' ' will fail when there are spaces, i.e, Address||123 Main ST

Comment: if you assume that the order remains constant and that names don't have spaces in them then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = Str.Split("||")[1].split(" ")[0] //Sam
str = Str.Split("||")[2].split(" ")[0] // Jones
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this `string firstname = originalstring.substring(indexof("FirstName") + 11, ((indexof("LastName) - indexof("FirstName") + 11 )`

this way you get to the first letter after || and till the first letter before "lastname" the same goes for surname you just switch firstname with lastname and lastname with adress

edit: my fault... it's not `substring.(indexOf...` but it's

`originalString.Substring(origianlString.IndexOf("FirstName) + 11, (originalString.IndexOf("LastName") - originalString.IndexOf("FirstName") + 11)` and when looking for last name it's not + 11 but 10 because `"LastName".Length + + "||".Length = 10`

Comment: Rob P. made it a bit cleaner then me:)