# Finding the index after a substring

Tags: c#, string, substring

Suppose you have a string ("haystack"), and a substring you want to search for ("needle"):

```
 string haystack = "D0B11234 AM21ANP AM23AN1";
 string needle = "AM21AN";
```

I'm looking for a way to find the index or substring *after* the substring being sought.

Calling [`IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the *start* position of the needle, such that `index = 9` in this case:

```
int index = haystack.IndexOf(needle);
```

My initial thought was to use [`LastIndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy(v=vs.110).aspx), but that returns the *start index of the last occurrence* of the needle in the haystack.

As is answered in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876107/c-sharp-substring-indexof) (and probably others), if you wanted to locate the character immediately following `needle`, it is required to increment `index` by the length of the needle like this:

```
int index = haystack.IndexOf(needle);
int indexAfterNeedle = index + needle.Length;
```

Is there a method (existing, or perhaps easy to extend) *aside from typing `index + needle.Length` every time* that allows you to determine the *ending* index of a substring?

Comment: You could do math with stringtosearch.Length() to determine that.

Comment: Isn't the end simply the start plus the length?

Comment: @EricLippert The end IS the start plus the length! This is perhaps a pretty trivial thing, but working through this got me wondering if `C#` contains a method that returns the end instead of the start (as `IndexOf` does). I'm currently doing this with `startValueFromIndexOf + string.Length`, just wondering if there are other methods available.

Comment: @CodeCaster `startIndex` only determines where to start looking; I don't believe it effects the value that `IndexOf()` actually returns.

Comment: @codeCaster it's very easy to understand what he's trying to do. Maybe not clear why it matters, but that's another story. To the OP: no. There isn't, Using startIdx and adding length is short and simple. No need for extra complexity to simplify that further.

Comment: @leigero it isn't to me, otherwise I wouldn't be asking those question. Maybe it's too much text for a very simple question that threw me off, I don't know.

Comment: @CodeCaster apologies, I realize I put way too much effort into such a simple matter, it's just curiosity. I have edited the question.

Comment: How about you reverse both of the strings?

Comment: @leigero *"Maybe not clear why it matters"* I know I've needed to do this frequently, it's not a big deal to add the extra code every time to add the someString.Length to the arguments, but having an extension method like CodeCaster submitted is pretty handy IMO. It's not a ton to write doing it manually each time, but after so many times you just say "I wish there was an existing method that did this..."

Comment: @levelonehuman would you mind me thoroughly editing your question so that it still conveys your original question but more concise? You can always roll it back if you don't agree. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster go for it! It did end up kind of messy :P

Comment: @levelonehuman how's this? Click "rollback" at revision 3 in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34320376/revisions) if you don't like it.

Comment: @CodeCaster looks good! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's nothing built into the BCL.

It's trivial to add yourself through an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static int EndIndexOf(this string source, string value)
{
    int index = source.IndexOf(value);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        index += value.Length;
    }

    return index;
}
```

Demo:

```
string testString = "D0B11234 AM21ANP AM23AN1";
string stringToSearch = "AM21AN";   

int endIndex = testString.EndIndexOf(stringToSearch);

Console.WriteLine(testString);
Console.WriteLine(endIndex);
Console.WriteLine(testString.Substring(endIndex));
```

Output:

```
D0B11234 AM21ANP AM23AN1
15
P AM23AN1
```

This may seem like an off-by-one error depending on your requirements, so you may want to change it to `index += value.Length - 1` to return the position of the last character of `value`, instead of the index of the character after that.

You also may want to [add an overload with an `int startIndex` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx), and actually call that one from the method above with a `startIndex: 0`.

And be sure to add error handling to the extension method, like throwing an `ArgumentNullException` and such.

Also, if the string to be found lies at the end of the source string, you cannot use the value returned by this method to take a substring of the source string, as it'll lie outside the source string.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to add `value.Length` to index instead of `source.Length`?

Comment: @E.Moffat yeah that's what quickly copy-pasting together an example in Notepad++ while eating gets you.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! Even if it is a really trivial thing, extension methods in general are still new to me and this wouldn't have crossed my mind - so thanks for teaching me something!

Comment: I guess you probably already know this but you could reduce it to `return (index >= 0) ? index + value.Length : index;`

Comment: Just linking [this MSDN page about Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for other readers, @levelonehuman and my own sake as I'm not very experienced with implementing him.

Answer (score 2):

While not using IndexOf(), if your needs may go beyond exact pattern matches, you could use a Regex:

This would allow you to do something like:
What is the position of the first non-whitespace character after my search string?

```
string testString = "D0B11234 AM21ANP AM23AN1";
string stringToSearch = "AM21AN";   
Match m = Regex.Match(testString,stringToSearch);
int endpos = m.Index + m.Length;

Match m2 = Regex.Match(testString,@"(" + Regex.Escape(stringToSearch) + @")\s*(\S)");

int nonwspos = m2.Groups[2].Index;
```

This returns the position of the P after your search string, but would also return the correct position even if there was whitespace after the string.